# How to Navigate in iOS App

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I am trying to have a simple Navigation in my iOS-Project but nothing worked. I am trying since hours and I just don't get it why it so difficult (I have Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 and Android Apps in the Store).

I have a View which is connected to my Class MainMenu. In the header, I refere to the header of mainmenu.h. And i create a object MainMenuView which is based on the Class MainMenu. In the m-File, I initialize the MainMenuView:

```
MainMenuView = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
```

Just for test purpose, I set a Title and this is the only thing which works:

```
[MainMenuView.navigationItem setTitle:@"Main View"];
```

I tried a lot of different lines but no lines does the job (simply show the MainMenuView...)

```
[window addSubview:[navController view]];
UINavigationController *newnav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:MainMenuView];
[self setNavController:newnav];
[window addSubview:[navController view]];
[self.navController pushViewController: MainMenuView animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I added this to the first line, because I read it in some tutorial, but did not help:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

So, simply I just wwant to display my MainMenu using UINavigationController. Later on, I want to use UINavigationController to navigate to specific Views by pressing specific buttons...

This line would actually crash my app:

```
[self.navController pushViewController: MainMenuView animated:YES];
```

Comment: I tried to make a action on a button to navigate to another view: UINavigationController... unitwithRootViewController and self presenViewController... - it showed a animation but the new window had the nav bar but was black, just unlike what i see in the storyboard. In the storyboard, i have a real, white, view with different buttons... so what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier, nothing else worked... But this is not written in any documentation or something else, I found it after hours of googling... :(